# How to get the dictionary key?

Tags: c++, dictionary, key

I have a structure :

```
struct node {
    map<string, string> data;
    node* left;
    node* right;
};
```

And I know there can be only one key-value pair in the data (I know I can use a pair, but the task is to do it with a map - realy strange task) )
So, how can I get the key in some node?
For example :

```
node t;
t.data...
```

Comment: If there can only be one element, then why not use the element as the member directly? The map seems unnecessary.

Comment: You're right. this is strange. Probably a good time to clarify the goals with whoever assigned the problem.

Comment: FYI, your code represents `std::list<std::map<std::string, std::string> >`.  Is this what you want, a list of dictionaries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`t.data.begin()->first` will do the work. But probably you should write the whole task 'cause it's really strange.

Comment: I have to make the English-Russian dictionary as a binary tree in which each node should be a map)